# ios Location Manager failing in ipad and working fine in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cllocationmanager

Here is my test to implement location service

```
-(void)setUpLocationmanager{
// Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
//ios8 location manager need this
//also update the plist with key "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    //[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSString *title;
        title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alertView show];


    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

}

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
    _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}



self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;


[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

}

and my problem is I am getting continuous location update in iphone but in ipad i am not getting continuous location updates the delegate -`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:oldLocation`- may or may not called for few times after that I am getting `locationManager:didFailWithError:`

In iPhone no issues but in ipad it randomly fails

My Initial step for location manager is as follows

1. Enable background mode in capabilities
2. Add NSLocationAlwaysUsageAuthorization to plist
   and I am assuming that my setup is correct since there is no issue in iphone

I Tested in the following condition also
1. I have repeated the same test for iPad iOS8 and iPad iOS9
2. I have tested it in `Xcode7.1` and `Xcode6.4` but the result is always same ie works in iphone but failing in ipad
3. enabled airplane mode in iphone (to disable the assisted GPS) and no issue in getting location. As far as i can think this is the main thing that is there in iphone and not in ipad

some comments saying that in ipad location wont work. But see the following pic i opened one sports tracking app parallely and it is plotting the route
[image]

when failing the error I am getting in locationManager:didFailWithError: is

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Any help appreciated

Comment: Most iPads dont do 'proper' GPS, its cellular assisted.  The phone has a proper GPS receiver though.  So you arent getting any info because none is being gathered, probably.

Comment: iPad (Wifi Only) don't have the GPS. It only uses the wifi network to approximate the location. iPad (Wifi + Cellular) model has GPS.

Comment: I am testing it on ipad Wifi version .But i think  the above comments are not correct because of the following facts. 1. i have a map in same view with correct current location updates 2. i used sports tracker app parallely and the route is plotting almost accurately

Comment: What is considered a significant update?  Due to the reliance on non-GPS and non-Cellular sources, the iPad you are using has a very inexact idea of where it is.  There may be a larger margin of error before it will report a change.

Comment: They still get a location, but they use a system that takes cellular (phone) data from masts to triangulate position.  It is not true GPS.  Thats why location manager is not getting a normal location.  Yes you still get a position, but once you switch off your phone signal, you will not.  Whereas on a phone, you can have no signal at all yet still get a perfect position. Try it yourself.